# Strange Message Displaying on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When I open the WordPress dashboard the following message is displaying at the top of the page:

index-php auto-fold admin-bar branch-5-4 version-5-4-1 admin-color-fresh locale-en-us no-customize-support no-svg">

[image]

I don't know what's going wrong. does anybody knows about it?

Comment: You have an error somewhere in the DOM of your admin page, seems like a missing ". Did you change any admin templates while you were working on the page?

Comment: I told my friend to customize the website but he does not know where did he change but he end up with this. And I also don't know where he made changes. The message is different for different pages but the ending message is same i.e admin-color-fresh locale-en-us no-customize-support no-svg">

Comment: The error is in the body tag... so I’m guessing whatever he did the effected the wp_head() or the way he enqueued things...  either way, tell him to troubleshoot the stuff that loads early.

Comment: He has no idea about it and the other thing is the plugin search does not work due to this problem. Where is wp_head() in WordPress?